# NSTimer perfomance of device

Tags: objective-c, events, nstimer, game-engine

I want to run a timer that watches my game for some events that occur during the gameplay.

I would include the timer in the did load function. So the Timer is checking permanently if event1 happened or not.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001
    target:self
    selector:@selector(check_status_event1:)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:YES];
```

I also try to set a pointer to the Timer to invalidate when needed.

```
- (IBAction)check_status_event1:(id)sender
{
    //_stepper_event1_status_check.value (0 = no / 1 = yes)
    if (_stepper_event1_status_check.value == 1) {
        _stepper_event1_status_check.value = 0;  //reset stepper again
        [self event1_go:0];
    }else{}
}
```

Question:

Is the interval of 0.001 o.k?

Is there a big influence to the device performance? Because there is permanently running an if statement (or more). Does it maybe also make the iPhone or iPad slower, when the game is sent to background via home button?

Can I use more of this timer at the same time? for example when I run 10 or 20 of them.

Is this the normal way to catch an event that occur during the game? For example a colidation of 2 objects. I also set some code with a timer after 1 sec (step1). after 2 sec (step2). after 3 sec (step3).... when I use such a timer, I can start the next step exactly at this time, when the step before has done. Maybe one step needs more then 1 sec. And I don't want to use animateWithDuration and Delay. And maybe an iPad 2 is slower in processing and reading the whole code as an iPad 4. And I don't want to start with step 2 when step 1 has not finished.

But what is about the performance of the iOS device. Is this a problem?

thank you
Philipp

Answer (score 0):

```
Is the interval of 0.001 o.k?
```

Probably not. "The effective resolution of the time interval for a timer is limited to on the order of 50-100 milliseconds". You may set it to 0.001 but you are unlikely to get your timer on time.

```
Does it maybe also make the iPhone or iPad slower, when the game is sent to background
```

No it won't slow down the device when in background. iOS stops timers when app is in background.

```
Can I use more of this timer at the same time? for example when I run 10 or 20 of them.
```

Yes you can, but you may find a better solution.

```
I don't want to use animateWithDuration and Delay.
```

That will make your life easier. iOS goes into extends to make your animation smooth even if the device is under load.

```
Is this the normal way to catch an event that occur during the game?
```

No, unless your game doesn't update much, e.g. a turn-base game with no animation. Delivery time of timer event is not guaranteed. It may slip significantly. You would want to update you game state smoothly on every iteration, which is normally a frame. Do you have a frame update loop in your game? That would be the place to check for collisions and count time if needs be.

You are talking about noticing an event. A better design would be to use "push" rather than "pull". When an event happens it notifies all parties interested, not vice versa.